# Specifying RAM in firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Trying to boost the memory of an existing cloud function using the GCP functions console. I've been able to perform this operation before using Edit Function/Variable, Networking, and Advanced Settings, but now after specifying my preferred memory limit I am taken to a secondary screen asking me to upload my code. This seems redundant, as I'd just like to redeploy with more RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Memory, CPU, region, runtime, and so on are all options you choose **at the time of deployment**.  They are not dynamically configurable options that you can simply tweak over time without redeploying.  You're being asked to upload your code, because you need to go through the process of deployment again.  The system doesn't assume that you wan to use exactly what you had previously.

Since you tagged this with "firebase", I'll assume that you're using the Firebase CLI for deployment.  In that case, you will have to [change the builders in your code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify) to use the new settings you want to apply to the next deployment.